# Passing variable (whose value is select query) to exists() function not working in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am passing dynamically generated query (stored in a variable) to exists() function but it is not working.

```
SET @TABLE ='MYTABLE'
SET @QUERY='SELECT * FROM '+@TABLE

IF(EXISTS(@QUERY)) PRINT 'RECORD EXISTS'
```

I have tried this too

```
    --IF(EXISTS(EXEC(@QUERY))) PRINT 'RECORD EXISTS'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pas a variable like that to the exist funtion.
All you can do is build dynamic sql and check if the rowcount after.

```
declare @table nvarchar(20)
declare @query nvarchar(200)

SET @TABLE = 'MYTABLE'
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TABLE

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query

IF @@rowcount > 0 
    print 'record exists'
```

The problem with this method is that the resultset of @query will also be retrieved.

You can try fixing that  like this :

```
declare @table nvarchar(20)
declare @query nvarchar(200)

SET @TABLE = 'MYTABLE'
SET @QUERY = 'if exists (SELECT * FROM ' + @TABLE + ') print ''record exists''' 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

**EDIT: the OP needs this in a function where you cannot call a procedure:**
SQL Server does not allows calling procedures in a function.
A workaround can be to add a integer variable in you function (@tablenumber int) and use it like this :

```
if @tablenumber = 0
begin
    if exists(select * from table1) print 'record exists'
end
else if @tablenumber = 1
begin
    if exists(select * from table2) print 'record exists'
end
and so on
```

This will work if the number of tables is not to big. (it will still work but the maintenance needed is not worth it)

Comment: I am using this logic inside a function but that not allows to call a procedure(sp_executesql) inside a function.

Comment: SQL Server does not allows calling a procedure from a function. There is not much you can do about that sorry

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: No unless you are OK in using a workaround that is not so dynamic anymore. See my updated answer

Comment: Last one is helpful for me